# moq ReturnAsync Object Directly

Tags: moq

For ReturnAsync, I can return a new List:

```
moq Setup ReturnsAsync(
                new List<Foo>()
                );
```

, but can I return an object directly?

```
List<Foo> list=new();
moq Setup ReturnsAsync(list)
```

Comment: Why don't you simply give it a try?

Comment: I did, but it seems to just be NULL, if I do that. Is it supposed to work?

Comment: Hmm, I've found a reference that it should work, so it must be my code, then;). Sorry

Comment: Please try to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to be able to help you.